# Create sign in with Xero button in next js app

Tags: javascript, next.js, xero-api

I am currently in the process of integrating Xero into one of our applications. To achieve this, I am utilizing Next.js for the client-side aspect. I have added a Xero auth script and a button with relevant classes to accomplish this as their explained in the documentation [add Xero Sign in button](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/xero-app-store/app-partner-guides/sign-in/)

In here you can see the code

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
          <meta name="xero-client-id" content="clientID" />
        <meta name="xero-scopes" content="openid,profile,email" />
        <meta name="xero-redirect-uri" content="https://localhost:5001/Authorization/Callback" />
        <script src='https://edge.xero.com/platform/sso/xero-sso.js' defer></script> 
      </Head>
      <main >
        <div >
          <h1>Login page</h1>
          <div>
         <span data-xero-sso data-label="Sign In with Xero"></span> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

but I getting this error

[image]

need your help to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Xero indentity server doesn't support single page apps such as those built with React

Answer (score 0):

```
interface XeroSignInButtonProps {
  signInUrl: string;
  label: string;
}

const XeroSignInButton: React.FC<XeroSignInButtonProps> = ({
  signInUrl,
  label,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://edge.xero.com/platform/sso/xero-sso.js';
    script.defer = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <span
      data-xero-sso
      data-href={signInUrl}
      data-label={label}
      data-size="large"
      data-height="50"
      data-theme="dark"
      data-border-radius="10"
    ></span>
  );
};

export default XeroSignInButton;
```

Comment: This worked in adding the button , the only hiccup is the button disappears at times

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).